# How can I get a list of the underlying delegates from an event using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

First, `GetInvocationList()` won't work, because I want to be able to get to them from outside the class. I assume it *will* work with some reflection magic, and that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Here's what I have right now:

```
fooEventDispatcher.GetType().GetField("FooEvent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var field = fieldInfo.GetValue(fooEventDispatcher);
```

I just don't know what to do with `field`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you fill us in on what the goal of looking through the invocation list is? Depending on the purpose, there may be an easier way than reflection to get the result you want.

Comment: @Joel: I want to unit test that an object is subscribing itself to an event. Testing the side effect of the invocation isn't a clean solution.

Comment: Why GetInvocationList() wont work? It is a public method and anyone from outside can call that method, unless your class is internal to the assembly.

Comment: @ferosekhanj: You can't use events like that. The only thing you can do from outside the class is `+=` and `-=`.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question I was thinking of public delegate instead of event.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work:

```
var fieldInfo = fooEventDispatcher.GetType().GetField(
                "FooEvent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var eventDelegate = fieldInfo.GetValue(fooEventDispatcher) as MulticastDelegate;
if (eventDelegate != null) // will be null if no subscribed event consumers
{
   var delegates = eventDelegate.GetInvocationList();
}
```

Also you should use `typeof(SomeFooClass)` instead of `fooEventDispatcher.GetType()` if the type is already known at compile time (which I assume it is).

Comment: Line 4 should be `MulticastDelegate eventDelegate = (MulticastDelegate)field;`