# Assign an event to a variable

Tags: c#, variables, events

Is it possible in C# (<= 4) to assign an event to a variable (and then use it)?

Something similar to this:

```
    public void WireEvent()
    {
        var controlEvent = ((INotifyPropertyChanged) _myControl).PropertyChanged;
        controlEvent += MyEventHandler;
    }
```

Comment: Not possible(without reflection or so). Why would you need a local variable? You can simply subscribe event without the local.

Comment: I need to wire/unwire the right event so I'd like to write a function to determine the event to wire/unwire.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel is right, you can use only reflection. Better dont use it. Try to change the logic so that its within the class MyControl, otherwise it is bound to create problem in future. If you want to access it using reflection, you can refer here -http://stackoverflow.com/a/6501406/442444