# Discover whether other event handlers are registered within WPF Application on specific event

Tags: c#, events

I'm trying to register an default event handler which is called (or at least executed) when no other event handler is registered.
Especially I'm trying to register a fallback event handler for the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event within a WPF application.

The problem there is that I'm can't be sure that an event handler is still registered. So the concept is to register an "fallback" handler.

The first thought was to look at the Invocation list but for that i had to override the AppDomain class and that's nasty.

Second idea was to extend the AppDomain class with a concept of fallback handlers.

```
private static event UnhandledExceptionEventHandler DomainUnhandledException;
private static event UnhandledExceptionEventHandler DomainFallbackQueue;

private static bool _registeredAppDomainExceptionHandler; 

public static void AddUnhandledExceptionFallbackEventHandler(this AppDomain appDomain,
        UnhandledExceptionEventHandler handler)
{
    if (!_registeredAppDomainExceptionHandler)
    {
        //we need to register our proxy first
        appDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
        _registeredAppDomainExceptionHandler = true;
    }
    DomainFallbackQueue += handler;
}

public static void AddUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(this AppDomain appDomain,
        UnhandledExceptionEventHandler handler)
{
    if (!_registeredAppDomainExceptionHandler)
    {
        //we need to register our proxy first
        appDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
        _registeredAppDomainExceptionHandler = true;
    }
    DomainUnhandledException += handler;
}

private static void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (DomainUnhandledException?.GetInvocationList().Length == 0 || DomainUnhandledException == null)
    {
        DomainFallbackQueue?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
    else
    {
        DomainUnhandledException?.Invoke(sender, e);
    } 
}
```

With this approach I register the fallback within the App.xaml.cs.

So the disadvantage I see there is that the users (we are within a modular application where other departments develop their own modules) still see the original `appDomain.UnhandledException` and maybe don't know to use the extension `AddUnhandledExceptionEventHandler()` method to register.

And secondly the user maybe register through this method but unregistered with the `-=` operator on the original event.

Oh and the user needs to include the name space where the extensions live...

So how would you solve this problem? Maybe there is a better way to get a fallback handler?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're solving here. Usually you'd just register a handler for this specific event early on in your program's start-up and leave it there. If you have some applications where developers are forgetting to do X, it's unlikely that a solution that requires developers to remember to do Y is going to succeed.

Comment: Did you try this?
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501288/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-underlying-delegates-from-an-event-using-reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501288/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-underlying-delegates-from-an-event-using-reflection)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes normally we would do that but in this particular case the "fallback" will quit the application. In the boot strapper we register an logger to these events but in case that the logger isn't registered we need to handle it. WPF has the default behavior to stay there but without the boot strapper the shell won't show up.

Comment: @mkok we won't go with reflection unless there is no other way..