# Copying Subscribers of Events to Derived Object

Tags: c#, inheritance, events, copy

Here is a contrived example I have:

```
using System;
namespace Example
{
    class Parent
    {
        public event EventHandler Event;
    }
    class Child :Parent
    {
        public string Data {get;set;}

        public Child Copy()
        {
            Child copy = new Child()
            {
                Data = this.Data
            }
            copy.Event = Event.GetInvocationList(); //This doesnt work
            return copy;
        }
    }
}
```

Since the child can't do everything the parent class can do to the event, I can't use .GetInvocationList(). Therefore, how would I be able to get around this in a simple way so that I can copy the subscribers of an event, made in a base class, in a child class?

**Most importantly, assume I have no access to the parent class, i.e. I'm deriving from a class in System.**

Comment: You can't do that. `Event`'s methods is only available from within Parent class. But you can use reflection, not so simple, but if you wrap it in an extension method.... Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501288/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-underlying-delegates-from-an-event-using-reflection)

Comment: @Michael Is there any other way? This seems very bug prone?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Event.GetInvocationList()` in the `Parent` class, then you access not the event but the auto-generated delegate field, which has the same name as the event. This is a private member so you cannot access it from a derived class.

However, by declaring an event by explicit add/remove accessors you can solve this problem:

```
class Parent
{
     protected EventHandler Handler { get; private set; }

     public event EventHandler Event
     {
          add => Handler += value;
          remove => Handler -= value;
     }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    private void SomeMethodInDerivedClass()
    {
         var handlers = Handler.GetInvocationList();
         // ...
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

If you cannot modify the base class you can access the private delegate field by reflection.

*Note*: To copy the delegate field you don't need to obtain the invocation list as you cannot assign an array of delegates to an event handler. All C# delegates are derived from `MulticastDelegate` so the value to assign will already contain all of the subscriptions. Please also note that even multicast delegates are immutable so don't be afraid of assigning the original delegate instance to the copy: when you add a new subscription to the original instance it will not be reflected in the copy (so this works somewhat similar to strings).

And the solution:

```
public Child Copy()
{
    Child copy = new Child()
    {
        Data = this.Data
    };

    FieldInfo eventBackingField = typeof(Parent).GetField(nameof(Event), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (eventBackingField == null)
        return; // oops, not an auto event, it has explicit accessors

    // copy.Event = this.Event:
    eventBackingField.SetValue(copy, eventBackingField.GetValue(this));
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: This is helpful but I as my bold statement says, I don't have access to the parent class. Any other suggestions?